# Android in Eclipse - No warning or error about non existing methods of previous Android versions

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, eclipse-adt

Recently I updated to Luna and I miss some feature I had in earlier versions.

My project has

```
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

so there are methods which doesn't exist in the earlier versions. I'm sure that Eclipse warned me about such methods when I used them in code, but this doesn't happen anymore.
I'm not sure where this problem is related to, maybe to Eclipse itself, to ADT (23.0.2) or to the project itself or maybe Maven? Any ideas about that and how to solve it to get warnings again?

Lint settings seem to be ok:

[image: Lint settings]

Comment: check the lint settings in the android tab under preferences

Comment: I updated the posting by a screenshot, they seem to be ok.

Comment: you should get a compile time error not a warning. Can you try to run it manually ?

Comment: If I build and run it (by Maven) I get a NoSuchMethod exception. I think there is some compiling issue, because when I add for example new layouts, then the content assist doesn't recognize it. I have to run mvn install to get the latest information. Same with new added graphics. Maybe it's the same issue.